# Why are tailwind animations not applied to a react component with an optional class according to state?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to make the typical CSS animations with tailwind but they are not being applied, could someone help me with this. Thank you.

```
{isOpen && (
    <ul
        className={`bg-gray-200 text-gray-900 border border-solid border-gray-300 shadow-lg rounded-md absolute top-9 transition duration-300 ease-in-out z-10 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700  dark:text-gray-50 ${menuRight ? ' right-0' : ''}`}
    >
        {items.map((item) => (
            <li
                key={item.labelItem}
                onClick={() => onSlected(item)}
                className="p-2 rounded-md cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-300 flex text-nowrap items-center gap-2 transition duration-300 ease-in-out dark:hover:bg-indigo-500 dark:hover:bg-opacity-15"
             >
                 {item.iconItem && (
                     <FontAwesomeIcon icon={item.iconItem} />
                 )}
                 <p className="inline-block">{item.labelItem}</p>
             </li>
         ))}
    </ul>
)}
```

I am waiting for the `<ul>` to appear with animation when displayed